# how to export postgres database from aws rds

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I have a Rails 4 app deployed to Elastic Beanstalk using Postgresql. My question is: what is the best way (or a good way) to export the database?

I tried to use `pg_dump` from the ec2 instance which is part of the RDS security group but the ec2 instance has a different postgres version (9.2.9).  I was also unable to make this happen using the AWS console.

Any general advice on how best to proceed would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`pg_dump` is the way to go, but sounds like you'll just need to ensure that the host running `pg_dump` is running with the same version as the RDS server instance.